# How to translate a letter into a specific word using the dictionaries I created?

Tags: python, dictionary, telephony

I want to write a program that asks the user for a message, then converts the message using the telephony codes, codes that translate each letter into a specific word.
Here is sample output from the program:

> This program will translate a message using telephony codes.
> What is your message? I love you, mom!
> India  Lima  Oscar  Victor  Echo  Yankee  Oscar  Uniform  Mike  Oscar  Mike

The solution I can think of is to replace the letter a to alfa and then b and then rest of the list but it is just time consuming;
My question is:
how can I use a for loop (maybe?) to set conditions and to convert all letters?

```
Basically you need to convert every letter into a new word using the dictionaries
```

"A": "Alfa",
"B": "Bravo",
"C": "Charlie",
"D": "Delta",
"E": "Echo",
"F": "Foxtrot",
"G": "Golf",
"H": "Hotel",
"I": "India",
"J": "Juliett",
"K": "Kilo",
"L": "Lima",
"M": "Mike",
"N": "November",
"O": "Oscar",
"P": "Papa",
"Q": "Quebec",
"R": "Romeo",
"S": "Sierra",
"T": "Tango",
"U": "Uniform",
"V": "Victor",
"W": "Whiskey",
"X": "X-ray",
"Y": "Yankee",
"Z": "Zulu",

Answer (score 1):

output = ''

```
for letter in list(word):
   if output == '':
      output = dictionary[letter]
   else:
       output = output + ' ' + dictionary[letter]
```

I hope this helps. It checks if it is the first word added to the output, and then determines whether or not to add a space.
word is the input, output is the result

Answer (score 0):

```
sample = "This program will translate a message using telephony codes. What is your message? I love you, mom! India Lima Oscar Victor Echo Yankee Oscar Uniform Mike Oscar Mike"

for letter, word in {"A": "Alfa", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": "Foxtrot", "G": "Golf", "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliett", "K": "Kilo", "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November", "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform", "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"}.items():
    sample = sample.replace(word, letter)
sample
>>> 'This program will translate a message using telephony codes. What is your message? I love you, mom! I L O V E Y O U M O M'
```

Answer (score 0):

so first before parsing the string I would suggest removing the spaces and special characters like punctuations. Either remove the punctuations or add that to the lookup dictionary

```py
lookup = {",": 'com',"A": "Alfa", "B": "Bravo", "C": "Charlie", "D": "Delta", "E": "Echo", "F": "Foxtrot", "G": "Golf", "H": "Hotel", "I": "India", "J": "Juliett", "K": "Kilo", "L": "Lima", "M": "Mike", "N": "November", "O": "Oscar", "P": "Papa", "Q": "Quebec", "R": "Romeo", "S": "Sierra", "T": "Tango", "U": "Uniform", "V": "Victor", "W": "Whiskey", "X": "X-ray", "Y": "Yankee", "Z": "Zulu"}
#here punctuations have been removed before hand
st = "This program will translate a message using telephony codes What is your message I love you mom India Lima Oscar Victor Echo Yankee Oscar Uniform Mike Oscar Mike".upper()
st = st.replace(' ', ',') #replacing spaces with comas
print(''.join(list(map(lambda x:lookup[x], st))))
```